Jmeter : How to execute Login request after every 30 minutes and pass the token to subsequent requests
In Jmeter, I am executing test suite for 2 hours, in which login token expires after every 30 minutes. I want to execute login once only and not throughout the test, but how can I generate the new login token after 30 minutes and pass it to the subsequent APIs,
Coz test runs fine for first 30 minutes since login is getting executed once, but after 30 minutes all APIs starts failing since token is expired.
Expectation is, when test starts, once Login is executed, it should execute only after 30 minutes to generate new token and rest APIs should keep running.
|- Thread Group
|- Once Only Controller
|- Login [from this token is passed to below APIs]
| - API_1
| - API_2
| - API_3
| - API_4
I tried, Flow controller but than the Login pauses for 30 minutes and meanwhile other requests does not get executed.
Flow Control Action

The options are in:

Use another Thread Group to generate/refresh the token each 29 minutes. Then you can pass the token to the main Thread Group via JMeter property or using Inter-Thread Communication Plugin. See Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups article for more details.
Put the request generating the token under If Controller and use __groovy() function to check whether 30 minutes have passed since last execution. However it will be more resource intensive.

